# Pandas : Not able to convert value in form of 1 and 2 metrics

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a input file similar to this

```
Order_id   ASIN         
1              abc1
1              abc3
2              cba2 
2              abc1 
2              bbc3
```

What I am trying to create a metrics where ASIN will be column and Order_id will be row and for whichever ASIN falls under specific Oreder the value should be 1 else zero something similar like below.

```
              abc1         abc3    cba2      bbc3 
Order id 

  1             1           1       0          0            
  2             1           0       1          1
```

I tried following to do that using pandas.

```
  bskt = pd.pivot_table(df,index='Order_Id', columns='ASIN', 
          fill_value = 0)
```

But this is not returning the desire result. Please let me know what might I am doing wrong here.

Alternatively I added a new column quantity and keep the default value of 1 for all rows in it.
I tried below

```
  bskt = pd.pivot_table(df,index='Order_Id',values='Quantity', columns='ASIN', 
          fill_value = 0)
```

But this is also not giving the correct result.

Comment: I saw that question earlier and use pivot but It gives me only 00 in all fields so I asked here

Comment: @jezrael please answer this if possible I am not able to find the answer in given example

Comment: Need `df = pd.pivot_table(df,index='Order_id', columns='ASIN', fill_value = 0, aggfunc='size')`